# Constructor within activity is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have been fighting with this error for a couple of hours and I am not able to continue. I need your help here!

I am trying to replace my previous TabNavigation at ActionBar by a ViewPager in SDK21, looking at comments within StackOverflow I found [this webpage](http://codetheory.in/android-pagertabstrip-pagertitlestrip-viewpager/), where the use of PagerTabStrip is described with an example, so I tried to implement it in my activity, however I am getting an strange error.

I tried to google the problem and all the suggestions are not really applicable to my problem (wrong parameters in the constructor are the usual errors) . I also reproduced the error with a simple Activity in order to avoid anything I have in my previous activity, but the error keeps. I attach you here the code I replicated isolated:

```
import android.app.Activity;   
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.adding_users_to_list);

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), this.getApplicationContext());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
}

class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // Create fragment object
        Fragment fragment = new DemoFragment();

        // Attach some data to the fragment
        // that we'll use to populate our fragment layouts
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page_position", position + 1);

        // Set the arguments on the fragment
        // that will be fetched in the
        // DemoFragment@onCreateView
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + (position + 1);
    }
}

class DemoFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout resource that'll be returned
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);

        // Get the arguments that was supplied when
        // the fragment was instantiated in the
        // CustomPagerAdapter
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_option)).setText("Page " + args.getInt("page_position"));

        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

I am getting in the call to the constructor the following error:

"The constructor TestActivity.CustomePageAdapter(FragmentManager, Context) is undefined"

In here:

```
 mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), this.getApplicationContext());
```

I have tried to introduce the Adapter outside and inside the activity definition and is still not working. Is likely to be something simple, but... I can't see it and I need other eyes. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the import of the activity to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Also change constructor to:

```
 mCustomPagerAdapter = new  CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this.getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your activity is used from the ADT:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

and the Fragments used from the support package:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

change the import of the activity to:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Comment: Personally I think they should just remove that darn duplication from the SDK, if anyone want they can use the support library...

Comment: What you are telling me is to extend the TestActivity from FragmentActivity instead of Activity? I tried that and I am getting the same error (I implemented it and rebooted eclipse just in case)